# can not add file in aws s3 bucket using postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to add a file in s3-bucket in my AWS account using postman. see below screenshot.

[image]

I pass **Host** in the header as a **divyesh.vkinds.com.s3.amazonaws.com** where **divyesh.vkinds.com** is my bucket name. and in Body I am giving **file** as **index.html** as file type like image below.

[image]

but it is giving me **The provided 'x-amz-content-sha256' header does not match what was computed.**
error. I searched for it but can't find anything.

Comment: How are you calculating the payload hash?

Comment: I am not calculating it at all.

Comment: Your PUT request has an authorization header and a custom x-amz-content-sha256 header. Postman doesn't supply those afaik so you must be doing it. Are they pre-configured in your Postman collection? How are they being populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check content-header. Add Content-Type as text/plain  and date in this format XX-XX-XXXX

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same problem. The issue was that, postman does not calculate the SHA. It defaults to a SHA of empty string **e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855**

So in the postman headers, add an explicit key **x-amz-content-sha256**. Caluclate the value of SHA256 for your file using a sha command and provide as the value. Below command works on linux flavors

```
shasum -a 256 index.html
```

Couple of other observations in the question.

1. You can change the Body as binary and choose the file you want to upload.
2. Provide the complete path including the file name in the upload URL. E.g. if you provide the URL as <your bucket name>.s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/test/index.html, the file will be copied to test directory in the bucket with name as index.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this situation recently, and the issue was that I was copying an active log file which changed between when my side calculated the hash and when the file was actually uploaded. My solution was to copy the file to a temporary location, then upload that stable file.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue once I changed the body of my request from form data  to binary I was able to upload my file no issues